# Find a file with particular substring in name

Tags: c#

I have a dirctory like this `"C:/Documents and Settings/Admin/Desktop/test/"` that contain a lot of microsoft word office files. I have a textBox in my application and a button. The file's name are like this `Date_Name_Number_Code.docx`. User should enter one of this options, my purpose is to search user entry in whole file name and find and open the file.
thank you

Comment: What code have  you written so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please [have a look](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string name = textBox2.Text;
string[] allFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\\");//Change path to yours
foreach (string file in allFiles)
    {
        if (file.Contains(name))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Match Found : " + file);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

G'day,

Here's the approach I used. You'll need to add a textbox (txtSearch) and a button (cmdGo) onto your form, then wire up the appropriate events. Then you can add this code:

```
    private void cmdGo_Click(object Sender, EventArgs E)
    {
        //  txtSearch.Text = "*.docx";

        string[] sFiles = SearchForFiles(@"C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Desktop\test", txtSearch.Text);
        foreach (string sFile in sFiles)
        {
            Process.Start(sFile);
        }
    }

    private static string[] SearchForFiles(string DirectoryPath, string Pattern)
    {
        return Directory.GetFiles(DirectoryPath, Pattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    }
```

This code will go off and search the root directory (you can set this as required) and all directories under this for any file that matches the search pattern, which is supplied from the textbox. You can change this pattern to be anything you like:

- *.docx will find all files with the extention .docx
- *foogle* will find all files that contain foogle

I hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: @Default There's mainy reasons really - it's just a matter of being able to think of them. I've mainly created this method so that the OP may expand it if required. Naturally, you could move the method to one line if you wanted. I mark methods as static when they contain no instance specific code. I would move method into a file related

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Directory.GetFiles($path$).Where(file=>file.Name.Contains($user search string$)`.

*Should* work for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Directory.GetFiles(string, string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) which searches for a pattern in a directory.
So, for your case, this would be something like:

```
 string[] files =
          Directory.GetFiles("C:/Documents and Settings/Admin/Desktop/test/",
                              "Date_Name_Number_Code.docx");
```

Then look through the `files` array for what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

if you need info about the files instead of content:

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(startFolder);  
  
IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> fileList = dir.GetFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```